# setInterval and function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this simple function:

HTML:

```
<div class="mhead">
 <div class="mTop"> 
   <a class="headline" title="" href=""> 
     <img alt="" src=""> 
     <span> </span> 
   </a> 
 </div>
<div class="tNav">
 <ul id="topt" class="tUl">
  <li title="http://www.site.com/761028497.jpg"> <a title="" href="">1</a> </li>
  <li title="http://www.site.com/761028497.jpg"> <a title="" href="">2</a> </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Function:

```
$.fn.inters = function (target) {
    this.find('li').hover(function () {
    var head = $(this).find('a').attr('title');
    var image = $(this).attr('title');
    var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(target).find('img').attr('src', image);
    $(target).find('img').attr('alt', head);
    $(target).attr('href', href);
    $(target).attr('title', head);
    $(target).find('span').html(head);
}).eq(0).hover();}

$("#topt").inters('.headline');
```

I want to add `setInterval` to this script:

```
$(function() {
setInterval( "inters()", 3000 );
 });
```

But the headline items doesnt change. How can I make change in `inters` function every 3000 ms?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your `setInterval` will attempt to call the function `inters()` every 3 seconds, which is probably not what you want.

What I **think** you want to execute is the following line:

```
$('#topt').inters('.headline');
```

If you want to do so you should create a function that will execute that line, like so:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#topt').inters('.headline');    
}, 3000);
```

The above will call `$('#topt').inters('.headline');` every 3 seconds.

Comment: @kevin, I have tested your way and @stecb's way but it doesnt work. There is a problem in my function but I cant find it.

Comment: @utopia: Could you post the HTML that is affected?

Comment: @utopia: Are you getting a javascript error? Because you seem to be missing a brace.

Comment: @utopia: Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J2ywA/ I've modified your code a bit but, could you tell me if it does what you want?

Comment: @kevin, this is a newheadline that content changes with hover. But I have add an automatic hover for this that content changes every 3 seconds. In jsfiddle, I want "1 2" contents change every 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something in this way:

```
function foo(){
    $("#topt").inters('.headline');
}

setInterval(foo,3000);
```